# Import HTML template file into vue.js script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm learning javascript and vue.js 3 by myself and I want to clean the vue.js script of my personal website because it's too long. I want to move the template I wrote in my vue.js script in its self file (in .vue or .html I don't care). Here is the vue.js script I import in my HTML page :

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            show: "",
            content: [...] //some stuff I use to fill the template
        }
    },
    template: `...` //my html/vue.js template I wante to put in another file
}
```

I tried the solution given on this forum : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-using-templates-from-external-file
with my template in a .html file

```
<!-- All my template here without anything else -->
```

and the following modifications to my .js script

```
export default {
    template: require('./relative/path/to/template.html'),
    data() {
        return {
            show: "",
            content: [...] //some stuff I use to fill the template
        }
    }
}
```

But I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` which seemed strange to me because my client support require and I use it in others websites. I tried several solutions to solve this error but none of them work.

I ask to chatGPT to give me a solution to my initial problem and so I tried another solution :
my template is in a .vue (or .html, I tried both) file as follow

```
<template>
  <!-- All my template here -->
</template>
```

and the following modifications to my .js script

```
import MyTemplate from './MyTemplate.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: "",
      content: [...] //some stuff I use to fill the template
    };
  },
  components: {
    MyTemplate,
  },
  template: `<my-template :content="content"></my-template>`
};
```

But I got `The loading of the module at the address 'https://mywebsite.com/path/to/ContentTemplate.html' was blocked due to a forbidden MIME type (" ").`. I think I understood what this error is saying but I have no idea of how to solve it. (And chatGPT too because it give me solutions that create a new problem and to solve the new problem it give me a solution that bring back the MIME error.)

I'm searching on the vue documentation and on forums but either I don't find anything that solve my situation or I've already seen my solution but I was too dumb to understand and apply it.
Which brings me to this point, where I'm asking the stackoverflow's community to enlight me.

Comment: If you're learning the framework, stick to the ways that are described in the official guide. It's possible but not common to extract a template to a separate file. It's unclear if you develop without a build step (so-called Vue CDN) or with one. In the latter case it depends on your toolchain, which is unknown

Comment: @EstusFlask
I've already followed the official guide (not absolutely entirely but most of it). That's precisely because I've already did it and I want to experiments some stuffs that I try to do that.
I import vue from `https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js` that is a development version. But, if I'm not misunderstanding, this is not a Vue CDN.
I just google what is a toolchain cuz that's the first time I heard this term but if I understood well : I'm not using any toolchain, I'm doing all by hands.

Comment: This IS "vue cdn". You're loading Vue from CDN server instead of bundling it from NPM package, hence the name. The point is that you're relying only on native browser apis when using vue this way and can't use a lot of features, this includes .vue, require() and other non-spec things. You need to use build tool like Vue CLI or Vite to have the same developer experience that's commonly described in the guides